# Powershell module not showing ExportedCommands

Tags: powershell

When I use:

```
Import-module testmodule.psm1
```

It will import my custom made Powershell module. However, the module seems to be emtpy no version number, Author, Copyrights, ExportedCommands etc. It used to work but all of a sudden it stopped working and I am not sure why.

Get-module output:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          {Export-BinaryMiLog, Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstance...}
Script     0.0        testmodule
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
```

testmodule.psm1 looks like:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls, 
Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3"

$manifest = Import-PowerShellDataFile "testmodule.psd1"
$version = $manifest.ModuleVersion
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle="testmodule $version"
```

When I run the commando below by itself:

```
Import-PowerShellDataFile "testmodule.psd1"
```

It will show all the information in my psd1 file like: version number, Author, Copyrights, ExportedCommands.

In addition when I run:

```
Test-ModuleManifest testmodule.psd1 

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0.1      testmodule                        {Blablabla, blablabla, blablabla...}
```

Then it also shows all the correct information. I tried to run the code in a Virtual Machine so a different environment than my host machine and I have the same problem.

I am not sure what to test or where to look anymore. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I added the following lines of code in the PSM1 file:

```
write-host $version
write-host $manifest.RootModule
```

This displays the right information so the testmodul.psd1 is being found by the script.

Comment: The Import-PowerShellDataFile must be failing when being run from the module right? Maybe try adding $PSScriptRoot to the path so it's surely looking in the right place

Comment: @SweetSheep thanks for your anwser. I tried adding it, but it is not making a difference. When I print the path everything seems to be running from the right locations as well.

Comment: I coincidentally needed to set this up on my own and seems like there's no need to import the psd1 into the main psm1 at all, it just works by existing. Can you post your directory structure and the relevant bit of `Get-Module -ListAvailable` with it unloaded too please?

Comment: @SweetSheep thanks again. The directory structure is:
testmodule.psd1 
testmodule.psm1 
Output (dir)
Scripts (dir)

What you mean with the relevant bit of Get-module unloaded? When the module is unloaded the relevant module is not there so not sure what to show.

Comment: Try following : Import-module testmodule.psm1 | Format-List -Property *

Comment: TLS only 1.2 and 1.3 can be used older version are obsolete.  SSL3 never existed and is a typo.  So use [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12, Tls13"

Comment: @jdweng Hi! I just tried it but it's not returning any additional information. It just runs all the code in the .psm1 file, but no error or extra information by adding the format-list.

Comment: You may be getting an exception and code is not completing.  Something in you inputs changed to cause output to change.  I've seen cases like this where one item gets returned instead of an array.  Then PS stops displaying results.  Solution was to force the single results into an array using following : `@(........)`.